# Closed form for linear recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$
\mbox{Given the following sequence}:\quad
a_{n + 1} = n + n\,a_{n}\quad\mbox{and}\quad a_{1} = 0.
$$

- How would one find the closed form of this $?$.
- This looks vaguely like something involving factorials.
- Finding the closed form is difficult, and I'm not sure how to start besides trial and error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $b_n=a(n)/(n-1)!$ to get $b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+b_n$. Then maybe you can see closed form for $b_n$.

Comment: There's always the use of generating functions...

Comment: The exponential generating fun ction is apparently $\frac{ze^{z}}{1-z}$.

Comment: OEIS sequence [A007526](https://oeis.org/A007526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Sil 23, letting $b_k=\frac{a_n}{k!}$,we can write
$$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$
and carry out telescopic summation, we get
$$b_2-b_1=1$$
$$b_3-b_2=\frac{1}{1!}$$
$$b_4-b_3=\frac{1}{2!}$$
$$............$$
$$b_n-b_{n-1}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$$
Adding all we get
$$b_n=b_1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k!}$$
$$\implies b_n=e\frac{\Gamma(n-1,1)}{\Gamma(n-1)}\implies a_n=e \frac{\Gamma(n) \Gamma(n-1,1)}{\Gamma(n-1)}=(n-1)e~\Gamma(n-1,1).$$
Here, $\Gamma[n,x]$ are incomplete Gamma functions e.g. $\Gamma[1,1]=1/e$ and we get
$$a_1=0, a_2=1, a_3=4, a_4=15,a_5=64,....$$

EDIT: Note that $\Gamma(n+1,1)=n\Gamma(n,1)+e^{-1}.$